# How to properly implement authorization with OAuth2 based on user credentials?

Tags: zend-framework2, oauth-2.0, credentials

I want create authorization system using OAuth2.0. Seems to be very easy, but I'm stuck with  this. All examples are about sending separate requests to OAuth server, for example:

```
curl -u testclient:testpass http://localhost/token.php -d 'grant_type=client_credentials'

(and similar requests to retrieve resource, or refresh token)...
```

Ok, this works fine, but this is not what I'm actually looking for. Firstly, I need only `client_credentials` and `refresh_token` grant types. The way how I see its work:

1. User sends me credentials
2. I authorize them(checking if somebody exists with such
   username&password combination)
3. If yes, I want to return access & refresh token to the user(set in
   cookies).
4. At this step I should retrieve that tokens, and sending user's credentials to
   the OAuth server via curl(internally I mean, e.g. in my
   Authentication controller :(, the same I found [at OAuth Demo](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-demo-php/blob/master/src/OAuth2Demo/Client/Controllers/RequestToken.php#L61)) seems to be possible solution, but it's awful as for me.

I'm stuck at 4 step. Is this only way to use OAuth server, can I just use its functions internally? Probably it won't work if I'll use functions separately. But how to do it properly?

**Update**
I've implemented separate service for its simple usage in controllers. Seems that I've finally found an answer. Correct me if I'm wrong.

**Update 1**
I've used already created by B. Shaffer server. Implemented my own options(e.g. to use another users table instead of oauth_users), and passed to server instantiation. I made it not as really separate server(I mean separate file, etc), but just separate name for it in Module.php, and all my custom configuration is placed there(or could be placed in some factory I guess).